# HTML - child element from one div override other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two consecutive `divs` in a `HTML` page

First `div` contains child `span` which is `relative` in `position`. That's why it comes over second div.

I have a click event associate with both divs.

When I click the part of the `span` which comes over second `div`, it triggers the first `div's` click event but I want here to trigger second `div's` click event.

Is there any way to achieve this.

[image]

```js
function div1Clicked() {
  alert('div 1 clicked');
}

function div2Clicked() {
  alert('div 2 clicked');
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
  height: 100px;
  width: 13%;
  background: red;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

#div1 span {
  width: 316px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 39px;
  position: relative;
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
  height: 100px;
  width: 13%;
  background: red;
  display: inherit;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="div1Clicked()" id="div1">
  <span>
    </span>
</div>

<div onclick="div2Clicked()" id="div2">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Picture don't help much, show us your code.

Comment: i like picture but code is important

Comment: Is there anything associated with the click event for the span? Can the clicks on the span be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any hover state on the child span, you can do it like this. Keep in mind this differs a bit from your html but it can be converted to your html/css easy, I just don't have the time to do it at this moment.

What you do is add `:after` on the two divs with a higher `z-index`, that will overlay the `span` and work as trigger areas for you javascript. Don't mind my "strange looking css" it's BEM. You can use your javascript triggers and it will work well. You can use `alert()` instead of `console.log()` if you are not familiar with devtools in your browser of choice.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/42oxddf4/)

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__column block__column--left js-action-1"></div>
  <div class="block__column block__column--right js-action-2"></div>

   <div class="block__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, voluptas!</div>
</div>


.block {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.block__column {
  width: 50%;
  height: 20rem;
  position: relative;
}

.block__column:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.block__column:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block__column--left {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.block__column--right {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.block__description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  background-color: white;
}


$('.js-action-1').on('click', function() {
 console.log('clicked the left column');
});

$('.js-action-2').on('click', function() {
 console.log('clicked the right column');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html><head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="div1Clicked()" id="div1" style="
    border: 1px solid gainsboro;
    height: 100px;
    width: 13%;
    background: red;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
">
<span style="
    width: 316px;
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 39px;
    position: relative;
">
</span>
</div>

<div onclick="div2Clicked()" id="div2" style="
    border: 1px solid gainsboro;
    height: 100px;
    width: 13%;
    background: red;
    display: inherit;
    float: left;
">
<div>
</div></div>
<script>
function div1Clicked(){
if($("div:first").width() < event.offsetX)
div2Clicked()
else
alert('div 1 clicked');
}

function div2Clicked(){
alert('div 2 clicked');
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Click the span element if trigger the event parent elemnet(div1) event, so does not get the correct output. But You get the output some check the condition.Please refer below snippets

```
function div1Clicked(){
if($("div:first").width() < event.offsetX)
div2Clicked()
else
alert('div 1 clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the span lies in div1, when it gets clicked, it will fire div1 click event only, even if it is overlapping the div2. So instead if you could use on click event of the green span, it might help. It will still fire div1 click event.

```
    <html><head></head>
    <body>
    <div onclick="div1Clicked()" id="div1" style="
        border: 1px solid gainsboro;
        height: 100px;
        width: 13%;
        background: red;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    ">
    <span style="
        width: 316px;
        height: 30px;
        background: green;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 39px;
        position: relative;
    " onclick="spanClicked()">
    </span>
    </div>

    <div onclick="div2Clicked()" id="div2" style="
        border: 1px solid gainsboro;
        height: 100px;
        width: 13%;
        background: red;
        display: inherit;
        float: left;
    ">
    <div>
    </div></div>
    <script>
    function div1Clicked(){
    alert('div 1 clicked');
    }

    function spanClicked(){
    alert('span clicked');
    }

    function div2Clicked(){
    alert('div 2 clicked');
    }
    </script>
    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `click-events` on the `span` are not necessary, you could apply `pointer-events: none` to the span which will ignore clicks on the span altogether.

```js
function div1Clicked() {
  alert('div 1 clicked');
}

function div2Clicked() {
  alert('div 2 clicked');
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
  height: 100px;
  width: 13%;
  background: red;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

#div1 span {
  width: 316px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 39px;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;  /*This will make the span click-through*/
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
  height: 100px;
  width: 13%;
  background: red;
  display: inherit;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div onclick="div1Clicked()" id="div1">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div onclick="div2Clicked()" id="div2">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below Snippet...

```js
$('.first,.second').click(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

```css
.first{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    left: 30%;
top: 30%;
}
.first:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.second:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.second{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="first">
      
    </div>
    <div class='second'>
    </div>
     <span>Hello World....</span>
</body>
```